# gentoo curl ssl - conflict

Tags: ssl, curl, gentoo

I'm not too much experienced within Gentoo portage and I am getting the following error when trying to update system:

```
gentoo package.use # emerge --ask --newuse --deep --with-bdeps=y @world

 * IMPORTANT: 2 config files in '/etc/portage' need updating.
 * See the CONFIGURATION FILES section of the emerge
 * man page to learn how to update config files.

These are the packages that would be merged, in order:

Calculating dependencies... done!
[ebuild   R    ] net-misc/curl-7.39.0  USE="ssl*" 
[ebuild   R    ] dev-java/jsch-0.1.49  USE="-doc*" 
[ebuild   R    ] dev-java/jzlib-1.0.7-r1  USE="-doc*" 
[ebuild   R    ] dev-java/jflex-1.4.3-r2  USE="-doc*" 
[ebuild   R    ] dev-db/hsqldb-1.8.1.3-r1  USE="-doc*" 

!!! Multiple package instances within a single package slot have been pulled
!!! into the dependency graph, resulting in a slot conflict:

net-misc/curl:0

  (net-misc/curl-7.39.0:0/0::gentoo, ebuild scheduled for merge) pulled in by
    >=net-misc/curl-7.20.0-r1[ssl] required by (dev-util/cmake-2.8.12.2-r1:0/0::gentoo, installed)
                              ^^^                                                                                                     

  (net-misc/curl-7.39.0:0/0::gentoo, installed) pulled in by
    >=net-misc/curl-7.25.0-r1[ssl=] required by (dev-python/pycurl-7.19.3.1-r2:0/0::gentoo, installed)
                              ^^^^
```

Comment: First of all do an `etc-update` maybe there are changes to the portage configs. Then try again. And did you do an `emerge --sync` before?

Comment: Well, I tried etc-update but there was no conflict regarding this. And of course I did emerge --sync before as well.

Comment: Yet, I am still getting the following:

Comment: In situations like these, I could often resolve them by aggressively unmerging stuff which causes those errors like `dev-util/cmake` and `dev-python/pycurl` and then emerge just `curl` in your case.

Comment: My advice is to remove `-ssl` anywhere you see it in `/etc/portage/make.conf` or `/etc/portage/package.use*`. In general, it is best to use the default USE flags and not arbitrarily set/unset them unless you know what you are doing, or else be ready for dependency conflicts like this one.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that this may be a use flag slot conflict. I see in the preview that your removing SSL support.

> net-misc/curl-7.39.0  USE="-ssl*"

However, your system configuration appears to be requiring ssl support. Portage recommends the following:

> It might be possible to solve this slot collision by applying all of
> the following changes:
>
> - net-misc/curl-7.39.0 (Change USE: +ssl)
> - dev-python/pycurl-7.19.3.1-r2 (Change USE: +ssl)

If you want to test this without making any changes to package.use try:

> $ USE="+ssl" emerge --ask --update --pretend --deep --with-bdeps=y --newuse @world

To make this permanent, add the ssl use flag to the package.use file

> $ echo 'net-misc/curl +ssl' >> /etc/portage/package.use
> $ echo 'dev-python/pycurl +ssl' >> /etc/portage/package.use

Then rebuild

> $ emerge --ask --update --deep --with-bdeps=y --newuse @world

Hopefully it should work with the new USE flags.

Answer (score 0):

There are two USE flag dependencies at work here.

---

The first one requires that `net-misc/curl` has the `ssl` USE flag set:

```
>=net-misc/curl-7.20.0-r1[ssl] required by (dev-util/cmake-2.8.12.2-r1:0/0::gentoo, installed)
```

The second one requires that `dev-python/pycurl` be installed with the same `ssl` USE flag that `net-misc/curl` has:

```
>=net-misc/curl-7.25.0-r1[ssl=] required by (dev-python/pycurl-7.19.3.1-r2:0/0::gentoo, installed)
```

---

So, the solution is to set the `ssl` flag on both `net-misc/curl` and `dev-python/pycurl`. This is the only way to meet both of these dependencies. You can read more about Portage dependencies from the [Gentoo Development Guide](https://devmanual.gentoo.org/general-concepts/dependencies/#built-with-use-dependencies).

There is no reason to disable the `ssl` USE flag. Most packages with the `ssl` flag are network-based and could probably use the security it provides. Besides, the SSL packages (`dev-libs/openssl`, `net-misc/openssh`) are pulled in through the [system set](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/System) so you aren't eliminating any extra dependencies by disabling it.